# Only one of two functions work at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the jquery.tools.js comes with 1.3.2.min.js (I test with this 1.4 and works fine, IF I remove the rest of statements (the dinamic menu).  Both of them works if I remove the other
Please Help me

```
<!-- scroll pics -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.tools.js"></script>
<!-- dinamic menu --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lavalamp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon.yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myriad.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#four").lavaLamp({
            fx: "backout", 
            speed: 700
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('li a', {hover: true});
</script>
```

Comment: improve your question there is missing words in it

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, your best course of action is to upgrade to the latest version of jQuery. 1.3.2 is over 3 years old. 1.4 is over 2 years old. That's ancient history now.

The current version is 1.7.2, available at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js or https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

You don't have to use the version of jQuery that's bundled with jQuery Tools.

Comment: Thanks Jordan,  I will try to update the version.  when I open your link it appears the code of jquery, How do I download or save to a .js file ?   Sorry if it is trivial but as I said , its my first experience with jquery issues.

Comment: I tried to update the jquery version to 1.7
If the good way is to save the text as a text file and rename it, I do it.  But now don´t work none of the two function.  Thanks again, I hope you can help me.

Comment: I´m sorry, another update.  I´ve now the 1.7.2 version.  The same as in the beginning.  Works only one at the same time, but not together.  I need help please

Comment: You can just use the link above as your src for the javascript. Google and jQuery provide the hosted version of the file. You can also use the hosted version of jquery tools, which has surely been updated as well: http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js

Comment: thanks Jordan.  I do what you said and use the hosted version of both files (jQuery and jquery tools) it not worked.  I also removed the jquery link as says in the jquerytools links. It doesn´t work any way.  Also when I used the hosted version of the tools the scroll doesn´t work alone as it did before.  What else can I do?

Comment: If you use the jquery tools CDN link that I posted above, you should not remove the jquery link. Please edit your question with whatever errors you are receiving.

Comment: I first tested without removing the jquery link, but also dont work.  I don´t receive any error ever.  The problem is that don´t execute one of the two functions.

Comment: Please Help me, I´m still with this issue